# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ in $(1,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Examine the uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ in $(1,\infty)$.

Here the point wise limit is $f(x) =1$ for $x>1$ and $f(1)=1/2$.

$$\sup_{x\in (1,\infty)} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \sup_{x\in (1,\infty)}  \frac{1}{1+x^{2n}} = 1/2 \not\rightarrow 0.$$
Hence the answer is No.

Am I correct?

Comment: The limit is $1/2$ when $x=1$.

Comment: Actually I did some typo. Now am I correct?

Comment: @Gary I thought that $\frac{1}{1+x^{2n}}$ is a decreasing function, so I calculated the maximum at $x=1$. Is it correct?

Comment: You're correct now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n:=1+ \frac{1}{2n}.$

Then

$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \to \frac{1}{1+e}$$

as $n \to \infty.$

Conclusion ?

Answer (score 0):

The pointwise limit of the sequence is $f(x)=1$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and consider
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \left|\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}-1\right|<\varepsilon.
$$
The above is equivalent to $$n>\frac{\log\left(\frac{1-\varepsilon}\varepsilon\right)}{2\log x},$$
and since $\lim_{x\to 1^{-1}}\frac1{\log x}=+\infty$, we see that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly.